# Run tests for a specific module in Magento2

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

Running the tests for Magento to using `php bin/magento dev:tests:run` takes a lot of time.
Is there a way to run the tests for a specific module only?

I'm a noob in (unit) testing so have mercy.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what the command does? I mean, in its code, perhaps it takes another argument (or list of).

Comment: @JulienLachal. Tried that. It only accepts one argument (type) that can be `all, unit, integration, integration-all, static, static-all, integrity, legacy, default`. And some general options like `-h, -q, ...` that are available for all commands. So nothing special about them

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Magento 2 use phpunit framework for running test.
You can run test per type and module with command:

```
{phpunit_executable} -c {Magentoroot}/dev/test/{type}/phpunit.xml[.dist] path/to/module/test/dir
```

For example:

- to run **unit** test for **Catalog**, you need run command

  `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/Magento/Catalog/Test/Unit/`
- to run **integration** test for **Catalog**, you need run
  `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog`

Currently only unit test moved to modules.
Also static and integration integrity test is working with all magento code.

Comment: So generally speaking the whole automated testing is still a mess even though they officially released 2.0.0?

Comment: @KAndy,  
I have run catalog module unit test, but cli displays error like this, Fatal error: Call to undefined function Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab__() in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edi‌​t/Action/Attribute/Tab/Inventory.php on line 89. In core module error are display.what is the cause of error. plz explain it.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, looks like your bootstrap file do not include app/functions.php where function __() defined

Comment: Yeah.. for me it is not running at all on 2.0.2 when i run "vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/Magento/Catalog/Test/Unit/" in magento root directory it gives me "PHPUnit 4.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Cannot open file "app/code/Magento/Catalog/Test/Unit/.php"." ...

Comment: @LachezarRaychev The Magento core codes is not in app/code/Magento path. Its moved to vendor/magento. Please try this command
`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/magento/module-catalog/`

Comment: @Franc You are right, the path app/code/Magento.. throws an error. Your method goes through.

Answer (score 15):

kandy's answer seams like the way to go, but in the mean time I found a quick and dirty way to do it.

Copy `dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist` to `dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` and replace

```
<directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/*/*/Test/Unit</directory>
```

with

```
<directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Test/Unit</directory>
```

and comment out the other `directory` tags inside the `<testsuite>` tag.

When you are done, revert your changes or remove `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: hello marius, how to do unit test using cli for catalog module?which command we have to run?base path is magento2/bin?

Comment: It's in the answer from KAndy.  `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/Magento/Catalog/Test/Unit/`

Comment: @Rakesh :: please try this updated command. `php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/magento/module-catalog/` Magento's core codes is moved to vendor/magento path.

Comment: how to run unit test for custom module using :       php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.disvendor/magento/module-catalog/

Comment: @SachinS. Just as I described. temporarily edit the `phpunit.xml` file and put the path to the module you want to test.

Comment: php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml app/code/Tagalys/Tglssearch   i get no tests executed

Comment: My edited phpunit.xml is <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/Tagalys/Tglssearch/Test/Unit</directory>    but what is Test/Unit

Answer (score 2):

just to add that by using Phpstorm IDE you can define Test configuration for your module and run it separately. [Running Tests in PhpStorm](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/test/unit/unit_test_execution_phpstorm.html)