# How we can create unit tests to everything we have created for our custom module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I have created a module in magento 2. And need to create the **Unit tests** for it.
I can see that Each core module has its own `Test` folder containing tests for each component like Controller, Block,Model,etc.

But they are hard to understand, and magento has not provided the tuttorial for the same. can anyone suggest any source where i can learn the unittesting framework from basics?

I got idea how to test it but I don't know how to create it.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_update.html

Please help to do this stuff.

Comment: We're working on tutorials. As for the documentation, it currently is more about integration tests, which will be the last thing that you create.

Comment: Okay so I will wait for it. thank you @benmarks

Comment: I also found the best solution for run the test http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/run-tests-for-a-specific-module-in-magento2?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Correction. The MTF is *functional* tests. We're investigating documenting other types of testing.

Answer (score 6):

The best I can suggest for now is reading up on PHP Unit and looking at other test scripts provided with the code base. I do not recall more unit testing examples being high on the doc teams list at the moment.

Some other reading that might be useful.

- There are lots of unit tests in the Magento 2 code base, such as https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Test/Unit/Block/NewsletterTest.php
- The M2 little samples at https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples are going to be refreshed shortly based on GA, but they are small examples with small example unit tests - might be easier to understand and copy
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/test-module.html (pretty terse)
- https://firebearstudio.com/blog/testing-magento-2-mtf-and-various-test-types.html
- https://travis-ci.org/magento/magento2 shows Travis running the M2 tests, broken this very moment still due to Composer changes near GA (being worked on)

Comment: Thanks Alan, Now we get idea how to write test class for custom module. Still I am getting problem while How to test a created test class methods. Other than M2 we are able to do it. But in m2 How we can test it using CLI ? We also perform the automation of test in m2 its working fine. Que is only limited for our custom module.