# Fatal error "Call to undefined function" with __() when running unit test in magento2

Tags: magento2, phpunit

I am run unit test for catalog module.
There are error display like below in cmd:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab__()
>   in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/Inventory.php
>   on line 89

And in Test folder error like below:

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Inventory->getTabLabel() /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/InventoryTest.php:148
```

what is the cause of issue for  error in magento 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you run this command line without phpunit.xml.dist:
`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit  app/code/Magento/Catalog/Test/Unit/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/InventoryTest.php`

You need to use phpunit.xml.dist, that contains attribute 
`bootstrap="./framework/bootstrap.php"`, because this bootstrap file includes
`BP . '/app/functions.php'`, that defines global function `__()`

To run this one test try to use this command line from the magento project root:

`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/InventoryTest.php`

Also look how to [Run tests for a specific module in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/run-tests-for-a-specific-module-in-magento2?rq=1)

Comment: hi, my code is inside vendor/magento/module-catalog folder. i want to unit test  for core module.

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya, I've updated my answer

Comment: from magento/bin, we have to run command you have given?

Comment: You should run it from the magento project root or you should specify absolute paths for the command line, e.g.
`/var/www/magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c /var/www/magento2/dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/InventoryTest.php`