# Integration test in magento 2, error display in cmd

Tags: magento2, integration-test

```
Fatal error: Class 'Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/TypeTest.php on line 17
```

above error are display in integration test for module.
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Check that you run an integration test with a phpunit config file for **integration** tests: 
`<magento2_root>/dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist`

This is an example how you can run your test from command line: 
`/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/TypeTest.php`

Also look how to [Run tests for a specific module in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/run-tests-for-a-specific-module-in-magento2?rq=1)

Comment: phpunit.xml.dist file is already there, but when call specific file they display error.

Comment: Could you show your command line?

Comment: be sure that your phpunit.xml.dist is from /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/

Comment: yes,file is on that location,My command line is, /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit$ php phpunit /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/TypeTest.php

Comment: I cannot find usage of /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist  in the given command. So phpunit will try to use config file from current directory. Do you run from /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration ?

If no try to define explicitly config file.

Comment: first go to this path  /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration and try your above answers command /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist /var/www/html/magento2/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/TypeTest.php, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33096/discussion-between-rocky-and-arkadiych).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem now, how did it going? is it can be solved following the answer?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195259)