# How to run static tests for a single/specific module?

Tags: module, magento2.3.2, tests

I am looking for a way to run **static tests** for a **single** module as my application is huge. So running static tests frequently and checking code consumes a lot of time.

As per my knowledge, Magento currently provides only **unit tests** on module level.

Let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to run custom testsuite according to your needs. Static tests are run with phpunit and the configuration file is in dev/tests/static/phpunit.xml.dist

So, from inside of this path do:

1. cp phpunit.xml.dist phpunit.xml
2. Edit new file with your editor and
   create custom testsuite in element. You can read more about
   configuring phpunit with a file in [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html)
3. When you create
   your testsuite enter command php ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit
   --testsuite="YOUR TESTSUITE NAME"

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/199947/73212)

Comment: Getting this message while running command - "No tests executed!" Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary refer this link it would be helpful.

Comment: Still not getting How I should configure it to work. Tried all the possibilities.

Comment: is this link **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299206/phpunit-no-tests-executed-when-using-configuration-file** relevant to you?